# Minimization of a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Let $T$ be a $n\times m$ matrix. I'm trying to solve

$$ \min \sum_i T_{ij}{\lambda_i}^{\frac{1}{\alpha_i}}$$
$$ s.t. \sum_i \lambda_i =1, \lambda_i \geq 0$$
for $j=1,2,...,m$. When $\alpha_i=\alpha$ for all $i$, this can be readily done by hand. The code I've written is

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
techniques = Dimensions[T][[1]];
factors = Dimensions[T][[2]];
αVec = ConstantArray[3/6, techniques];
λVec = Array[λ, techniques];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, techniques];
FactorNeeds = Transpose[T].λVec^(1/αVec);

varVec = λVec;
zerosVec = ConstantArray[0, Length[varVec]];
temp = Table[FactorNeeds /.
Flatten[
  Minimize[{FactorNeeds[[j]], onesVec.λVec == 1, 
    varVec >= zerosVec}, varVec, Reals]][[2 ;; 4]], {j, 1, 
factors}];
minmax = Table[temp[[j, 2]]/temp[[j, 1]], {j, 1, factors}]
minKL = Min[minmax]
maxKL = Max[minmax]
```

and it works fine when $\alpha=0.5$ (in the code `αVec = ConstantArray[3/6, techniques]`). However, if I try to set $\alpha=\frac{4}{6}$  or $\alpha=\frac{5}{6}$ it just keeps running and does not return an answer. The solution, in both cases is easy to compute; for instance, for $j=1$ (just plug the appropriate value for $\alpha$):

$$ \lambda_1=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}}+2^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}}} $$

$$ \lambda_2 =\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}} \lambda_1 $$

$$ \lambda_3 =2^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}} \lambda_1, $$

which, of course, add up to one.

Comment: Your objective function is not a polynomial for $a=4/6$ or $a=5/6$, but it is for $a=3/6$.  I suspect that is the reason.

Comment: Can this be done analytically if the function is not an polynomial? It might be very tough to solve it. Have you tried it for a finite series? The infinite might be troublesome.

Comment: @Michael E2 Perhaps I should not call it a polynomial, but I don't think this can be the cause. I've edited the question to indicate the exact values of the solution for $\alpha=\frac{4}{6}$ and $\alpha=\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: @Gladaed It can be done, at least provided $\alpha_i=\alpha$ $\forall i$. I don't understand your comment regarding infinite series. As a matter of fact, I'm only interested in this problem when $T$ has finite dimensions.

Comment: OK, it seems using `Solve` on the Lagrange multiplier system seems to work quickly.  (I thought `Minimize` was getting stuck because the effective degree of the system for $a=5/6$ is something like $6^3$, but the crit.pt equations form a simple system.  `Minimize` must be checking that the crit.pt. is a minimum, which perhaps turns out to be complicated.)

Comment: Try changing the inequality constraint to `Thread[1 + zerosVec >= varVec >= zerosVec]`.

Comment: Taking \[Alpha]Vec = ConstantArray[0.312, techniques]; instead of ConstantArray[3/6, techniques]; and NMinimize instead of Minimize, I obtain @NMinimize::nrnum: The function value 0.721478 -0.00102546 I is not a real number at {\[Lambda][1],\[Lambda][2],\[Lambda][3]} = {-0.11029,0.22083,0.88946}.".

Comment: @Patricio: I had a similar problem as yours, and I changed the constraint from  `==` to `<=` solved my problem but there was a lot of slackness. If you are lucky, you will also hit the perfect equality too. I think `Mathematica` is checking the `==` constraint, that is why it take so long.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Michael E2, it works fine, but why does this help?

Comment: @user64494, I want to avoid using `NMinimize` it causes other problems, but thanks

Comment: @TugrulTemel, I'm following Michael E2's advice, it seems more inocuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analysis over compact domains is generally easier than over open and unbounded domains.  (For instance a continuous function on a closed, bounded domain is guaranteed to have a minimum.)  While the boundedness of `onesVec.λVec == 1, varVec >= zerosVec` can be inferred, apparently it is not; so adding explicitly  an upper bound `onesVec >= varVec` helps `Minimize`.

```
temp = Table[
   FactorNeeds /. 
    Flatten[Minimize[{FactorNeeds[[j]], onesVec.λVec == 1, 
        onesVec >= varVec >= zerosVec}, varVec, Reals]][[2 ;; 4]], {j,
     1, factors}];
minmax = Table[temp[[j, 2]]/temp[[j, 1]], {j, 1, factors}]
minKL = Min[minmax]
maxKL = Max[minmax]
```

The output for `αVec = ConstantArray[4/6, techniques]` is

```
{961/294, 732/803}
732/803
961/294
```

My guess is that without the extra bound, `Minimize` is having a difficult time proving it has found the global minimum.

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael E2

Comment: @Patricio You're welcome.

Comment: Code is slightly neater as

`minmax = 1/
  Apply[Divide, 
   FactorNeeds /. 
    Last /@ (Minimize[{#, onesVec.λVec == 1, 
          onesVec >= varVec >= zerosVec}, varVec, Reals] &) /@ 
      FactorNeeds, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [Weierstrass parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) of a [superellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid) (similar to what I did in [your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193563)) to ease the task of minimization; an additional advantage of this approach is that the positivity constraints are quite easy to impose:

```
vec[u_, v_] := {((2 u)/(1 + u^2) (1 - v^2)/(1 + v^2))^2,
                ((2 u)/(1 + u^2) (2 v)/(1 + v^2))^2, ((1 - u^2)/(1 + u^2))^2}

With[{mat = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}}, α = 2/3},
     ArgMin[{#, 0 < u < 1 && 0 < v < 1}, {u, v}] & /@ ((vec[u, v]^(1/α)).mat)]
   {{1/Sqrt[13], 1/2 (-3 + Sqrt[13])},
    {Root[13 - 35 #1^2 + 13 #1^4 &, 3], 1/3 (-2 + Sqrt[13])}}

FullSimplify[vec @@@ %]
   {{9/49, 4/49, 36/49}, {16/61, 36/61, 9/61}}
```